# My SVG image ignores its stylesheet when used as background image

Tags: css, svg

I'm have an SVG icon that I style using CSS. The CSS is loaded from within the SVG file itself using a `<link>` tag.

When I use that SVG as a background image though no styles are applied while visiting said SVG directly, it works fine.

**Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/tINjHgmQLxvETzV8MjYi?p=preview)**

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how SVG works when used as an image. The data must be complete in a single file in order to protect user's privacy.

The mental model you need is that it's going to work and act in a similar way to a raster image, they are single files too.

You can still use a `<link>` tag but you'd have to encode the data as a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) within the svg file itself.

Comment: If I understood well what you said, I'm guessing that embeding the SVG inside an `<object>` tag instead, I can style it using an external CSS file. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, the single file restriction is only for images.